# goliath installation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, goliath

I have installed `goliath` gem but now any console rails command fails and returns :

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rack::Chunked
/home/Sites/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/Sites/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How can we explain that and how to debug ?

Comment: What's on line 7 of  `config/application.rb`?

Comment: @jefflunt here's `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)`

Comment: @jefflunt sorry, when writing my post, I copy pasted some content from my console and I missed some critical line !

Comment: @jefflunt I finally got it, see my answer if you interested ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer. I had to precise where to find the `Rack` module in my gemfile

```
gem 'goliath', :require => "goliath/rack"
```